# How to fix HTML canvas element and its coordinates across different screen sizes?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I've spent the past two weeks making a game with a few friends using the HTML canvas tag and JavaScript. None of us have any prior experience with a project of this scale, so considerations of browser/screen-size compatibility wasn't on our minds. The game runs and looks fine on our laptops (all have similar screen sizes), but it looked bad when we sent a link to another friend whose screen size differs greatly from what we had in mind.

To discuss the layout of the game in greater detail, it's set up with the canvas element acting as the actual game with a series of divs sitting below the canvas to represent things like a dialogue box or the pause menu (only one of these divs is shown at a time with the others being hidden).

The game is gridbased in that every object, from the wall tiles to enemies, has a size relative to some constant blockWidth (defined below) which itself is relative to the desired amount of squares on-screen, numSquares (also defined below).

Changing the canvas's height and width properties in JavaScript did successfully fix a ratio of the canvas size and ensure that the wall and floor textures loaded in their proper place. The player and other NPCs, however, appear at odd places onscreen, sometimes not showing up onload at all.

I'm not quite sure what to attribute this problem to, but I think it has something to do with canvas' coordinate system not mixing well with the admittedly poorly executed block system we put in place.

```
//some relevant misc variables
var numSquares = 30;
const blockWidth = 1132 / numSquares * 0.75;
screen.width = 1132;
screen.height = 600;

//some relevant player variables
stats.x = 678;
stats.y = 600;
stats.width = blockWidth * 3 * 0.37;
stats.height = blockWidth * 3;
```

Again, I suspect that the problem has something to do with the fact that the tiles that render correctly (i.e. wall and floor textures) have their coordinates in terms of blockWidth whereas the tiles that render incorrectly (i.e. the player) have their coordinates as regular numbers.

Is there a way to go about adjusting our game for different monitor sizes other than revamping the entire coordinate system?

Comment: Have you tried setting a scaler that follows the size of a container etc; [Scaled/Proportional Content](https://css-tricks.com/scaled-proportional-blocks-with-css-and-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

try this meta which will solve cross platform screen (laptop, Computer, Tab, Mobile)problem:

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is using hard coded values for your variables. If `stats.x = 678;`and your screen is 480px wide (for example), the `stats` will fall out the screen.

Also: `screen.width` and `screen.height` is a hardcoded number. Probably what you need is something like: `screen.width = window.innerWidth` and `screen.height = window.innerHeight`

What I'm missing from your *relevant misc variables*: In your code you have this:

```
var numSquares = 30;
const blockWidth = 1132 / numSquares * 0.75;
```

Where 1132 is in fact the `screen.width`. This means that you don't have a `grid` as you say. This means you have only ***1** (one)* row of squares. Alternatively you have 30 squares per row, and in this case you have a grid.

Also, it would be nice to see how you draw your grid. I would do it like this:

```
for (let y = 0; y < ch; y += cw / numSquares) {
  for (let x = 0; x < cw; x += cw / numSquares) {
    let o = { x: x, y: y, w: blockWidth, h: blockWidth };
    drawRect(o);
  }
}
```

Where `drawRect` is a custom function to draw a rect. Since your `blockWidth = screen.width / numSquares * 0.75;` I'm assuming you let a gap between rects, but this is assuming.

As I've commented before you can't give your `stats` hard coded values. You will need to calculate these values in function of your grid cells. For example your `stats.x` may be the x of the 5'th column of your grid and the `stats.y` may be the y of the 3-rd row. But this is again assuming and I may be wrong.

Next comes a code example. Please take a look and let me know if this is what you need.

```js
const screen = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = screen.getContext("2d");
let cw = (screen.width = window.innerWidth);
let ch = (screen.height = window.innerHeight);

let stats = {};

let numSquares = 30;
let blockWidth;

generateGrid();

function Init() {
  // a function to re-generate the grid and re-draw the stats when screen.width and/or screen.height changed
  cw = screen.width = window.innerWidth;
  ch = screen.height = window.innerHeight;
  
  generateGrid();
  drawStats(5, 3);
}

// recalculate everything on resize
setTimeout(function() {
  Init();
  addEventListener("resize", Init, false);
}, 15);


// some useful functions
function drawRect(o) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,.05)";
  ctx.fillRect(o.x, o.y, o.w, o.h);
}

function drawStats(x, y) {
  stats.x = x * cw / numSquares;
  stats.y = y * cw / numSquares;
  stats.width = blockWidth * 3 * 0.37;
  stats.height = blockWidth * 3;

  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillRect(stats.x, stats.y, stats.width, stats.height);
}

function generateGrid() {
  blockWidth = cw / numSquares * 0.75;
  for (let y = 0; y < ch; y += cw / numSquares) {
    for (let x = 0; x < cw; x += cw / numSquares) {
      let o = { x: x, y: y, w: blockWidth, h: blockWidth };
      drawRect(o);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

If this is not what you need, please update your question, and add more explanations and more code.